# Keyboard layout is correct within tty of Alpine Linux, but not with XOrg and DWM

Tags: linux, alpine-linux, xorg

I installed Alpine Linux on my daily driver laptop with dwm, dmenu, st and XOrg as instructed [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Dwm). Initially, I set my keyboard mapping as "gb gb" in the 'alpine-setup' command, and this worked fine (all the keys were in the right place) while still in the tty. When I installed Xorg and the suckless tools this did not hold true; the keymapping was set to the default US keyboard layout. When I exit X and return to the tty the layout is fine, which shows the problem is on the side of Xorg or DWM. I've tried adding the following to my .xinitrc, to no improvement:

```
setxkbmap -layout gb
```

How would I change the keymapping of Xorg and suckless tools to the UK keyboard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `setxkbmap` as it is not installed by default, and you should run this command from the terminal first to test it does work as intended before you add it to the `.xinitrc file.

Instructions are on [the wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_setup_scripts#Keyboard_Layout_.28optional.29).

---

```
# apk add setxkbmap
```

Then try

```
$ setxkbmap gb
```

In order to make it persistent add this section to /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "Keyboard Default"
    MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
    Option      "XkbLayout" "gb"
EndSection
```

Another way to change the keymap when logging into X is to use `~/.xinitrc`, adding:

```
setxkbmap gb &
```